# failed to connect to database using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to ask about connecting db with c#.
I have read http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm and written my code, but the connection doesn't seem to be working.

This is my code:

```
string connetionString = null;
SqlConnection connection;
SqlCommand command;
string sql = null;
SqlDataReader dataReader;
connetionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbabc;User ID=admin;Password=qwerty";
sql = "UPDATE ppd,brg,cmp SET WHERE";
connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
try
{
    connection.Open();
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dataReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(2));
    }
    dataReader.Close();
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
}
```

Did I write something wrong? The error message shown always says "Can not open connection"!

Comment: do you have sqlserver  running on localhost

Comment: What is the line in which you get the error?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the catch block and inspect the detailed error message in the ex variable.

Comment: It's probably correct.... in that either you don't have sql server running locally or the database doesn't exist

Comment: Without the error message its anyone's guess. Is TCP/IP Enabled? Does localhost map to 127.0.0.1? To many unknowns, lots of questions for clarification @lalaland please respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exception thrown should be a SqlException. Check the ErrorCode on the SqlException and look it up here...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-error-messages

Rather than catch(Exception ex) your code should do this...

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    ....
    connection.Close();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Can not open connection ! ErrorCode: {ex.ErrorCode} Error: {ex.Message}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Can not open connection ! Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment below, the alert of sql server

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check server name

if you install SQL server (Standard) on your computer, server name named is (local) or .

Comment: There is no server, its using localhost.

Comment: you try use "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=dbabc;User ID=admin;Password=qwerty"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS create a data source and test the connection string. Go to data> Add new data source. There is find your database server and create the correct string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. I can verify it. Please check your connection string and SQL query. Especially your SQL query. It seems to be wrong.
Try to execute the query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. If there is an error in your query, you can easily find it there.

**SQL Update Syntax**

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

Recommended Readings
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

To verify the connection string,

1. Open the **Server Explorer** pane. ("View" menu, "Server Explorer" or
   use the key shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).
2. Right-click on the Data Connections, Select **Add connection** and then
   press **continue** after selecting Microsft SQL Server as the Data source.
3. Select **Refresh** and click down arrow and then select your SQL server.
   If you cannot find it, enter the server name manually.
4. You may also have to enter the SQL server credentials.
5. Select or enter your database name & then press **Test Connection**.
6. If you see a **Test connection succeeded** message, then your SQL server is working.
7. If you want, you can also get connection string by pressing **Advanced..** button and then copying the connection string

[image]

In addition, try to an add exception message to catch block. That way, you can easily find the error.

```
MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! \n" + ex.Message);
```